# Paste at cursor location anywhere in system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, paste

I want to be able to “paste” text at any location on my desktop.. so if I was working in a word doc or any other program where I could use the paste command and pressed F5 a Form would pop up and select from a list of preformatted text slices (I have already got keyboard hooks in place for this) the part I’m having trouble with is how do I make the program paste preformatted text in to the location that the cursor was at before the chooser popped up.

Thanks in advance for any help..

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to register a global/system hotkey.  I would recommend though having some unique combination because a lot of programs use just F5 to perform functions (i.e. browser refreshes, visual studio building, etc.)

Check out this tutorial:  http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/180436-global-hotkeys/

You'll also want keep track of the current window when you trigger the event and then paste the content to that window, to do the actual paste, check this out:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bill/archive/2012/06/09/programmatically-paste-clipboard-text-to-a-cmd-window-c-or-c.aspx

Comment: "the part I’m having trouble with is how do I make the program paste preformatted text in to the location that the cursor was at before the chooser popped up."

- i don't see anywhere in the link that explains the solution to my problem, can you be more specific ?

Comment: It's a windows API call that allows you to send text to a window.  Google the function and you'll find more information about it.